# How to make a rest call over ssl to a service in Azure service fabric from local machine?

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-service-fabric

I have followed this https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/https-in-service-fabric-web-api, created a service in service fabric. The cert was created from KV. I downloaded certificate from KV. And I'm trying to call from my local mahchine. But I get 403 exception.

```
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); 

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certPath); 

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes); 

 

            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert); 

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl); 

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler); 

 

            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

Exception:
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Inner Exception 3:
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

How can make this call?

Comment: You are getting a response 403 which means the issue is not SSL.  SSL is obsolete but is still a general term that indicates TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 is being used.  When TLS fails you never get a response.  You are getting a 403 response so the connection is completing and TLS is working.  Most likely you are failing authentication.  Your link is from 2016 which is old and the authentication method is no longer being used.  Most system in the last year have been moving toward OAUTH 2.0 authentication.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean ssl auth is not supported?

Comment: SSL was an encryption method for connections.  It was replaced with newer algorithm.  The newer algorithms are still generically called SSL.  So ssl auth is really TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.

Comment: yeah, I understand that. So I can't just simply add cert to httphandler, that is no longer supported. I need to use token-based auth.

Comment: TLS and Token-based authentication is two different protocols.  TLS is used to encrypted the connection at the transport layer.  Authentication at the application layer to allow users to login to the server.

Answer (score 0):

> The exceptions shows that the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
> Check if the certificate is installed correctly on the machine.

Enabling HTTPS in an [ASP.NET Core service running on Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint).

If you have a certificate `PFX` file, import the certificate into the `certificate store`.

```
PS C:\mycertificates> Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath .\mysslcertificate.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "!Passw0rd321" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

```
private X509Certificate2 FindMatchingCertificateBySubject(string subjectCommonName)
{
    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = store.Certificates;
        var matchingCerts = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    
    foreach (var enumeratedCert in certCollection)
    {
      if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(subjectCommonName, enumeratedCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, forIssuer: false))
        && DateTime.Now < enumeratedCert.NotAfter
        && DateTime.Now >= enumeratedCert.NotBefore)
        {
          matchingCerts.Add(enumeratedCert);
        }
    }

        if (matchingCerts.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Could not find a match for a certificate with subject 'CN={subjectCommonName}'.");
    }
        
        return matchingCerts[0];
    }
}
```

Adding [TLS/SSL certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex,portal) in Azure App Service

[image]

And [configuring TLS mutual authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth?tabs=azurecli) for Azure App Service.

[image]

For more information, refer to the [MS Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal.md) and [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188300/load-ssl-certificate-in-azure-service-fabric-for-custom-tcp-service).

Comment: I don't have this Azure App Service. It's just an application running on VMSS in a service fabric cluster.